# jQuery animate with setinterval

Tags: jquery

my jQuery Code :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setinterval(function(){
        $("#animate").animate({'margin-left':'50px'},1000)
        $("#animate").animate({'margin-left':'-50px'},1000)
        },2000); 

        });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="animate">sdfdsfdsfsdfsdfds</div>
```

I want to do animation that will go every 5 sec. What wrong ?
Thanks !

Comment: Do you have a problem?

Comment: 2000 = 2 seconds. That's the first thing that's wrong.

Comment: *Never* use `setInterval()` with animations; it will only lead to failure.

Comment: @KevinB: ah....k, thanks for the correction

Comment: @BradM: Can you recommend an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/3GHaf/

`setInterval` is case sensitive. Camel case it and it works.

Answer (score 10):

My preferred solution. This way, your animation will be 100% truly synchronous and will not suffer from overlapping animations. Trust me, while the other answers use `setInterval()` and it "looks" like it works, these solutions will inexplicably fail after enough iterations due to the asynchronous nature of javascript. Also, it only does *one* DOM lookup for the element and makes it a jQuery object just once as well.

```
jQuery(function($){
    (function swoop(element) {
        element
            .animate({'margin-left':'50px'}, 1000)
            .animate({'margin-left':'-50px'}, 1000, function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    swoop(element);
                }, 5000);
            });
    })($('#animate'));
});
```

Comment: Even though this can be confusing to those just starting with JS, I would recommend this as the top answer. As Brad stated using timeInterval with animation always ends up causing overlap and side effects because eventually the time sync goes off.